# How to remove debugging from an Express app?

Tags: node.js, redis, express, socket.io

I would like to remove the debugging mode. I am using `express`, `redis`, `socket.io` and `connect-redis`, but I do not know where the debugging mode comes from.

[image: Node debug]

Someone has an idea?

Comment: Sounds like socket.io is outputting this. You forgot to mention your using socket.io

Answer (score 227, accepted):

**Update**

To completely remove debugging use:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app, { log: false });
```

Where `app` is node.js http server / express etc.

---

You forgot to mention you are also using [socket.io](http://socket.io). This is coming from [socket.io](http://socket.io). You can disable this by [configuration](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO):

```
io.set('log level', 1); // reduce logging
```

Comment: I just tried this, but I'm getting TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set' ... what's wrong? I have io = require("socket.io")

Comment: @user644745: It works for me if you set `io` to `require("socket.io").listen(app)` (or something similar). Thanks much for the answer, those logs were verbose and messing up the console.

Answer (score 7):

Just configure the log level to number 1 to avoid income unnecessary messages.

You can figure out more information about Socket.IO options on this [link](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO).