# How to disable websocket writing debug message

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Is there a way to disable `debug - websocket writing 5:::` message that constantly come up in the console when the websocket sending something, the message is being to chatty.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807775/socket-io-remove-debug-mode (OP didn't explicitly mention s/he is using socket.io, but the question tagged as such, and the accepted answer refers to socket.io.)

Comment: I find this question better than the linked duplicate, as it applies solely to socket.io, the linked question has other frameworks involved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to set log level on socket.io instance:

```
io.set('log level', 1);
```

Lower number will give you less info ( with `0` I guess none? ).

Answer (score 1):

include this in the app.js where you have server code

```
io.set('log level', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no more up to date.

According to http://socket.io/docs/logging-and-debugging you have to use the debugging scope

`DEBUG=* node yourfile.js`

in order to output debugging messages.

However, for a example, when I have "chat_server.js"
and apply

`DEBUG=* node chat_server.js`

then Node.js tells me:

`DEBUG=* node chat_server.js
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *`

Anyone having an idea why scope '*' is not accepted?

Comment: That looks like good syntax if you're running on a Linux based system. Any chance that you're using Windows?