# Is there a way to build Node without a debugger?

Tags: node.js

I am building node.js v0.8.11 under windows 7 and would like to exclude the V8 debugger feature for security reasons.

In other words, `node --debug main.js` should not spin up a debugger resulting in following output...

```
debugger listening on port 5858
```

Node would ignore the --debug directive.

Is there a way to build Node without the debugger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807775/socket-io-remove-debug-mode

Comment: FYI looking at the node `configure` and `node.gyp` files in the source distribution, I didn't see an easy `configure` flag you can just disable, but I also tried commenting out some lines containing "debug" in `node.gyp` and recompiled, but that didn't work. I'm almost certain this will require you to rebuild node as you state, and I also think it's probably possible, but I don't know the specifics of how to do it.

Comment: Why do you think removing the debugger will improve security? Explain your usecase, you're probably trying to Do It Wrong.

Comment: The requirement is the server source code remain inaccessible.  I have been able to build node with server code bundled using _third_party_main approach.  Then I encrypt node in attempt to satisfy requirement.  This works, unless the running app is accessed by debugger.  Also, it is expected that the server will not be running in a secure environment, hence the need to lock the code down.