# Removing heartbeat debug messages from socket.io

Tags: socket.io

While writing an app that uses socket.io, I'm finding that the heartbeat debug messages drown out the debug messages I want to see. What's the best way to shut off the debug messages for only the heartbeat?

Comment: This answer tells how to shut off all messages, but it also kills the debug messages that I _do_ want to see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807775/socket-io-remove-debug-mode

Comment: why not just disable heartbeat instead. You can always enable it for deployment

Answer (score 1):

#### Removing heartbeat debug messages from socket.io

Set up your socket.io with dynamic environmental configurations, and for the development environment turn down the 'heartbeat interval'

Here's some tips, most of them come from the [Configuring-Socket.IO](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) page of the socketIO v09 wiki.

```all-node
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

// This is sugar for if process.env.NODE_ENV==='production'
io.configure('production', function(){

  // send minified client
  io.enable('browser client minification');  
  // apply etag caching logic based on version number
  io.enable('browser client etag');          
  io.enable('browser client gzip');  // gzip the file
  io.set('log level', 1);           // reduce logging

  // enable all transports 
  // (optional if you want flashsocket support, 
  // please note that some hosting
  // providers do not allow you to create servers that listen on a 
  // port different than 80 or their
  // default port)

  io.set('transports', [
      'websocket'
    , 'flashsocket'
    , 'htmlfile'
    , 'xhr-polling'
    , 'jsonp-polling'
  ]);
}); 

io.configure('development', function(){
  io.set('heartbeats', false); //removes heartbeats
  io.set('log level', 1);      // reduces all socket.io logging, including heartbeats.
});
```

So do that, and then you're good on the heartbearts being on (the default) in production, and while you're at it -- you got the basic suggested production settings.

Also, depending on framework, or where exactly in the express/socket.io/top-level-app way of making things, you might have a setup like.

```all-js
app.io.enable('browser client minification');
```

or

```node
app.configure(function() {
  app.enable('junny')
  app.set('foo', 'bar')
});
```

So, to then control the heartbeats, first make sure you're getting the most out of your express/api logging, so load your app like this:

```bash
$  DEBUG=* node ./app.js
```

Then detect if you're in the development env (most top level way):

```node
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  io.set('heartbeat interval', 60*750);
}

// 60*750 = 45000ms = 45 seconds.
```

That would be turn the heartbeat interval to 45 seconds.

One can find all options at the [socket.io configuration wiki page](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO), a blockquote most relevant to this question:

> **heartbeat timeout defaults to 60 seconds**
>
> The timeout for the client, we should receive a heartbeat from the
>   server within this interval. This should be greater than the heartbeat
>   interval. This value is sent to the client after a successful
>   handshake.
>
> **heartbeat interval defaults to 25 seconds**
>
> The timeout for the server when it should send a new heartbeat to the
>   client.

If you want the heartbeats/message still then adjust those times upward, you'll have to test on your own system, but follow the general guideline/ratio and then adjust/test from there.

Comment: The answer to the OP on keeping the heartbeat message but slowing it down would be done by plugging into the suggested configuration higher values for '"heartbeat timeout" defaults to 60 seconds' and '"heartbeat interval" defaults to 25 seconds'.

Comment: And if all things are working correctly, then you could try something like `io.set('heartbeat interval', 750*60)` but up the 'heartbeat timeout' too then.